# Facebook like and Tweet counter issue due to query string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter, facebook-like

I have added Facebook & Twitter likes/tweet count button on products page. But it have observed quiet strange behavior. When there is no like it appears like in **fig01**.

[image]

When i **like**, its likes added to all products likes (From 0 changed to 6), while **twitter** count remains to **'0'** as shown in below **fig02**.

[image]

**The possible issue i think is that its ignoring query string value** i.e. **fig03**

[image]

I will be grateful if someone tells me possible solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly go to this URL and enter your URL to check is their any issue with your URL.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I was getting the same issue, **because my page was session dependent**, so i have made my page session independent then my Facebook like works absolutely fine.
May be you are getting that kind of page Redirect issue.

Comment: ooh... you found it... i have same issue, this page its session dependent not accessible directly in new session. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please guide how can I implement the like functionality in a session dependent page?
Scenario:
I have a e-commerce site, the user logs into my site and can see all products. The user can like(Facebook like) any product and the count should be increased on that particular product page.
Please guide!